# Angular in memory web api null body in post

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I have a post method in my angular app that has a null body. The in memory web api keeps giving the null does not have item.id error, but if I pass {} instead of null it works fine.

I don't want to have to change my actual post call for the in memory web api testing, so was wondering if there is any way to make my in memory web api not try to add anything or convert the null to {}. Basically my post method doesn't do much besides ping the server

Comment: of course, it will give u null error for item.id, you are accessing id property of a null value. when you pass {} and you access its property id, id is null not the item.

Comment: Yes, my question was whether there was any way to make the in memory web api not try to access the id property if it is null

Comment: try sending undefined instead of null. in-memory-web-api has undefined checks but not for null

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately getting the same error with undefined as well

Comment: @aks94 did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, just had to change to {} temporarily and remember to change it back

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yourself. After playing around with the [in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) trying to override the `post` method similar to the readme notes for the `parseRequestUrl` I didn't have much success; only getting part way there.

Instead I've opted to use the [Angular `HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which seems like the logical decision now looking back.

Create a HTTP interceptor class that checks for a null POST body. If found, clone the request as [it should be considered immutable](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) and set the body to an empty object `{}`. If there is a POST body then continue on with the request as normal. Then import the interceptor in the `AppModule` and include in the modules `providers` array.

Create file `http-post-interceptor.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
 HttpEvent,
 HttpInterceptor,
 HttpHandler,
 HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpPostInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // if request body is falsey
    if (!req.body) {
      // clone immutable request and set empty POST body
      const request = req.clone({ body: {} });
      // continue with our modified POST request
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    // else continue with the unmodified POST
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Import the `HttpPostInterceptor` and `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` into `app.module.ts`

```js
// ...
import { /*...*/ HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpPostInterceptor } from './http-post-interceptor';
// ...

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpPostInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  // ...
})
```

That's all there is to it.

This has solved the problem for me in my local environment so I'm no longer getting the errors noted in your question.

**Disable in production build**

Since `in-memory-web-api` is typically a non-production tool you may want to exclude this in your production build. Do so by importing your `environment` settings and performing a check if the production property is `true` or `false`. This could be done either in the interceptor or the module as per your needs. An example below is showing this via the `AppModule`.

Import your `environment` settings into `app.module.ts`

```js
// ...
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'; 
// ...

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    environment.production ? [] :
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpPostInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
  // ...
})
```

---

*Note: some import paths may differ depending on your project structure and if you are using Angular 6, notably the `Observable` import from `rxjs`*